# How can I use an alias in a function?

Tags: bash, bashrc, alias, functions

In my dotfiles I have [some functions](https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/blob/b02da017a593569f8d82df696611debbc0ad1c8a/common-setup/bash.d/bash_aliases_functions#L171) that rely on aliases or functions to exist for them to work. For some reason, I can get them to reference other functions I have created, but not aliases for commands. How do I fix this?

Example:

```
function open-dotfiles-commit(){ 
    xopen https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/blob/$1; 
}
```

If I have an alias `xopen` (`alias xopen=xdg-open`), the `open-dotfiles-commit` command will fail with `xopen: cannot find command`. On the other hand, if I replace the alias definition with a function called `xopen` (`function xopen(){ xdg-open; };`) it works!

I have even tried setting `shopt -s expand_aliases` in the same file as where I define the aliases - unsuccessfully. The alias and functions file is sourced by my `.bashrc`.

Comment: Can you post `~/.bashrc` and the alias file?

Comment: @j-money I linked to the whole setup in my github dotfiles repo. It is way to complex/involved to post here, as it consists of 3-4 intertwined files. I did get a correct answer, though.

Comment: Simply use `eval` in front of your command.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases):

> Aliases are expanded when a function definition is read, not when the
>   function is executed, because a function definition is itself a
>   command.

I'd bet that your aliases are defined after these functions are defined. Try defining the functions later.

For reference, I tested `foo () { ll "$1"; }`, using the `ll` alias from the default `.bashrc`, and it worked fine.

Runnable example:

```
def-before() { do-foo; };    
alias do-foo="echo foo u!"    
def-after() { do-foo; };

def-before 
# prints "do-foo: Could not find command"

def-after
# prints "foo u!"
```

Comment: That was exactly it. I edited your post and added the executable example I verified your answer with.

Answer (score 3):

[Olorin's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1123188/66226) did not solve my calling-aliases-in-a-shell-function problem. I recommend avoiding bash aliases, because (quote from the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases) below): `For almost every purpose, shell functions are preferred over aliases.`

To illustrate by converting `do-foo` in [Olorin's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1123188/66226) from an alias to a shell function (while also making sure to [add semicolons for one-line shell functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24636016/605356)), defining said `do-foo` shell function (that was originally an alias) before using it in another shell function, and for fun: redefining `do-foo()` and then recalling `def-after()`:

```
$ do-foo()    { echo 'hello foo'; }
$ def-after() { do-foo; }
$ def-after
hello foo
$ do-foo()    { echo 'this is fooey'; }
$ def-after
this is fooey
$
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
$
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
$
```

### More details

I had the same error as the OP in one of my bash scripts and [Olorin's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1123188/66226) did not solve it. This is apparently because aliases (by default) do not exand in non-interactive environments, like most all my bash scripts (including the one I mention above), as highlighted below. Once I converted all my aliases to shell functions everything worked as expected.

I now avoid bash aliaes and try to instead exclusively employ [shell functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions).

Excerpts from [the bash manual section on aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases):

1. `Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt (see The Shopt Builtin).`
2. `For almost every purpose, shell functions are preferred over aliases.`